# finding Ker(T) of a parameter's linear transformation

Tags: linear-transformations, matrix-equations, harmonic-functions

I am suppose to find the ker(T) of linear transformation of:
$$
G\begin{pmatrix}a & d \\ c & b\end{pmatrix}=
a+\frac{b+c}{2}x+\frac{b-c}{2}x^2
$$

the form $T:V \to W$

My problem is that I don't really know how to read the right side of the equation, is that a vector? A polynomial?

Am I supposed to take the right side of the equation and make it equal with 0?

Comment: Please do not use pictures.

Comment: The linear map is called $G$ and not $T$. The domain is the vector space of $2\times2$ matrices, the codomain is the vector space of polynomials (of degree at most $2$). You have to prove $G$ is linear, then compute the kernel.

Comment: Yes. You set the right hand side equal to $0$.

Answer (score 0):

The transformation shown is a linear transformation from the space of $2 \times 2$ matrices to the space of polynomials of degree two-or-less, i.e., $V$ is the vector space of $2 \times 2$ matrices, and $W$ is the space of polynomials of degree two-or-less.

I echo Dietrich's comment: please post equations, not pictures. Search for "MathJax" to find out how to post equations in general.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint**

$$G\begin{pmatrix}a & d \\ c & b\end{pmatrix}=
a+\frac{b+c}{2}x+\frac{b-c}{2}x^2=0\iff a=b=c=0$$

Comment: That’s a lot more than a hint. It’s basically the answer to the question.